# Android - Distance to items - RecyclerView

Tags: android, location, android-recyclerview, intentservice

I'm struggling in finding the proper way to achieve the following:

**Context:**
I have a recyclerView that displays items retrieved from firebase. Each item has a longitude and a latitude.
I need to display the distance to the item based on the user location, on some activities only.

**Is this the right way to proceed?**

1. The activity request for location permission
2. If permission is granted, an intentService (implementing a
   LocationListener)
       retrieves the current user location.
3. onHandleIntent sends an intent
           containing the location (latitude, longitude)

From here I'm stuck, I know I have to deal with a ResultReceiver?

**Problem : updating the viewholder / recyclerview**
The RecyclerView and Items would already been displayed, but once I have the location, I would update the distance to the item.

**Question**
How should I handle the update from the RecyclerView?

I hope my question is clear enough.

Thanks you for your help,

Comment: you don't really need to get the location in a service, do it in activity or a custom class managed for location things. For the part about updating a recycle view - its pretty easy to update recycle items by calling its adapter.notifyDataSetChanged

Comment: The thing is that it might take time to retrieve the location. This is why I'm thinking to using a service.

Comment: in modern devices/play services framework, location is usually cached and retrieved in less then 2-3 sec. Worst case scenario i can imagine will be 20-30 seconds.

Comment: Thanks! I will try your suggested way then.